# Linux incompatible with work access points?

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

just started a new job.  When I connect to the network at work using Kubuntu 16.04 it takes a few minutes to reach a destination (if it reaches it at all).  I don't have this problem at other places (home, the hotel etc.).  Others at work are using Windows and Mac and have normal speeds on the network.  I also get normal speeds when I connect via my Android phone.  But my 16.04 laptop has slow networking only when using the network at work.  How can I diagnose this issue and is it possible the problem is with the network at work itself?

Comment: Does the network use some sort of additional authentication, such as RADIUS, or do you need to log in with a web browser after you connect (captive portal) ?

Comment: How to you measure your network speed? Using ping-times or just how by feeling? Is the slowness somehow related so some specific protocol/technique (i.e. using smb)

Comment: You could consider using Wireshark to take a deeper look on the packages if you feel comfortable

Comment: 1) can you ping using addresses and if so are the ping times normal (if yes, could be just a DNS problem....) 2) Can you use *traceroute* on some address and see if your packets take a direct route, and/or compare with what you get on your colleagues' stations (the Windows command used to be "tracert" IIRC).

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, so I guess I'll "answer" :P

The first step, I'd say, would be to compare the terminal output of "ipconfig /all" on a Windows laptop (or "ifconfig" on a Mac, although it's very cluttered from what I recall) compared to that of "ifconfig" on your Kubuntu 16.04 laptop.

You can also get some verbose information from your Android phone by 'becoming a developer' (ie. going into Settings -> "About phone" and tapping on "Build number" a bunch of times) and then, in the Developer Options, enabling Wi-Fi Verbose Debugging. This'll make the Wi-Fi section in Settings much more verbose. Alternatively, you can open the dialer and run "*#*#4636#*#*" (this may not work on all devices, but it does if they're close to stock, ex. Nexus devices) which brings up the hidden Testing menu which includes "Wi-Fi information" -> "Wi-Fi Status" and should at least tell you the RSSI.

Combine that with the "iwconfig" command on you Kubuntu laptop and you should have enough information to start comparing some things and seeing if there's some obvious difference between the connection your Kubuntu laptop is making and what others are.

As to what's going on, my initial guesses would be that either the Kubuntu laptop isn't getting the right gateway for some reason, or that it's not negotiating a decent frequency and thus the RSSI is bad or the TX rate is being severely limited. Those are just spurious guesses, however; more information is definitely needed, including very much as per the comments folks have already made (which again, I would've joined in on, but for some weird reason Stack Exchange makes the lower-tier methods of textual interaction the ones hardest to get the 'points' to be able to do!).